# SQL WHERE IN clause with a list of objects that have ids?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a couple of SQL statements in C# that I need to add a range so that my SQL statement is similar to:

```sql
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE SOMETHING IN (value1, value2, value3 , ...);
```

I have a list of objects which have ids that I would like to substitute for the values. How would I go about this without a for each statement?

I have three of the classes with an id string of 12, 2, and 5:

```cs
public class inventoryItems
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: More information would be helpful - are you using an ORM? If so, which one?

Comment: try creating a string with Ids. like "'<id>','<id>'..."

Answer (score 0):

If you're using straight ADO.NET code you could do something similar to generate the T-SQL:

```
class Program
{
    public class InventoryItems
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new[]
        {
            new InventoryItems {Id = "One"},
            new InventoryItems {Id = "Two"},
            new InventoryItems {Id = "Three"},
        };

        var idsToDelete = string.Join(",", items.Select(x => "'" + x.Id + "'"));
        var deleteStatement = $"DELETE FROM InventoryItem WHERE Id IN ({idsToDelete})";

        Console.WriteLine($"TSQL - {deleteStatement}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```